# PostgreSQL COPY FROM STDIN Expressions

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am attempting to use COPY FROM STDIN to import data into my table. One of the columns in my table is of type geometry. My command looks something like this...

```
COPY "WeatherStations" ("Station_ID", "Station_Code", "Station_Name", "Station_Location") FROM stdin;
1       KAVP    WILKES-BARRE    ST_GeomFromText('POINT(41.338055 -75.724166)')
2       KOKV    WINCHESTER      ST_GeomFromText('POINT(39.143333 -78.144444)')
3       KSHD    SHENANDOAH      ST_GeomFromText('POINT(38.263611 -78.896388)')
...
```

However, I think it is attempting to insert the text "ST_GeomFromText('POINT..." and failing instead of evaluating the expression and inserting the result of the expression. Does anyone know what might be going on here and how I can get the actual geoms inserted?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I had a bad time figuring out how to bulk copy/load geometry data into PostGIS using the COPY FROM STDIN command, I couldn't find official documentation on this topic.

Altering the column during the bulk load ([the ALTER TABLE / SET DATA TYPE / USING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216891/postgresql-copy-from-stdin-expressions#comment13139595_10217292)) was not an option to me because it is [only supported in PostGIS 2.0+](http://blog.opengeo.org/2012/03/06/postgis-2-0-new-features-typmod/) for the Geometry type, nor was acceptable the [use of a temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10217292/822735).

There is indeed a direct way to do it (at least in PostGIS 1.5.2+).
You can simply rewrite the data for your copy statement this way, using a simple WKT (Well-known text) representation for your Geometry data:

```
1       KAVP    WILKES-BARRE    POINT(41.338055 -75.724166)
2       KOKV    WINCHESTER      POINT(39.143333 -78.144444)
3       KSHD    SHENANDOAH      POINT(38.263611 -78.896388)
```

If you have enforced a SRID constraint on the geometry column you'll have to use the following syntax (in this example the SRID is 4326) known as EWKT (Extended Well-Known Text, which is a [PostGIS specific format](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_GeomFromEWKT.html)):

```
1       KAVP    WILKES-BARRE    SRID=4326;POINT(41.338055 -75.724166)
2       KOKV    WINCHESTER      SRID=4326;POINT(39.143333 -78.144444)
3       KSHD    SHENANDOAH      SRID=4326;POINT(38.263611 -78.896388)
```

Closing note: there must be no space between "POINT" and the opening parenthesis "(", or the COPY will still return error saying your geometry data has an invalid format.

Comment: For anyone playing along at home, this will also work for `COPY FROM` for CSV.

This should be better documented in PostGIS.  It took me a better part of an afternoon to find your post.  Thank you very much for your contribution.

Comment: Still valid in 2017. At least I can avoid `shapely`'s slow `wkb_hex` function.

Answer (score 2):

You could omit the function wrapping the text, import into a temporary table with text column, and then run INSERT/SELECT into the permanent table with the function doing the conversion in that step.

```
INSERT INTO "WeatherStations"
  ("Station_ID", "Station_Code", "Station_Name", "Station_Location")
  SELECT "Station_ID", "Station_Code", "Station_Name",
         ST_GeomFromText("Station_Location")
    FROM "TempWeatherStations";
```

Comment: This is basically what I ended up doing. I add the data into a text column, create a temporary geometry column, convert the data, then drop the old column and rename the new one. Not the prettiest, but it works.

Comment: If you're going to do that in one table, you could simplify the process slightly, I think, by altering the column type using the USING clause for conversion..

Comment: Did not know about the ALTER TABLE / SET DATA TYPE / USING syntax! Much prettier than adding and removing columns.

Answer (score 0):

You will keep all the values in `.csv` file and try like this:

```
CAT /path/file/demo.csv | psql -u <username> -h <localhost> -d<database> 
-c "COPY "WeatherStations" ("Station_ID", "Station_Code", "Station_Name", 
"Station_Location") FROM stdin;"
```

This will work.

Answer (score -1):

Point's value looks something like this: `0101000020E6100000DA722EC555552B40CDCCCCCCCC0C4840`.

I typically keep `latitude` and `longitude` columns in my tables and build spatial data with triggers.

I don't know how to copy `POINT`s from stdin otherwise.